# Diferencia entre import y require

Tags: javascript, backend

estoy aqui hoy para conseguir un poco de informaciónm mas concisa jeje.

Me gustaría saber cual es la diferencia de cuando se hace un import a un require.

Toda esta duda surge porque quiero generar un archivo de funciones las cuales quiero exportar para que desde otro archivo pueda importarlas y utilizarlas pero me salen errores diciendo

```
Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

o

```
Unexpected token 'export'
```

Para que se entienda un poco mas imaginemos que tengo un **archivo_1.js** y **archivo_2.js**

El **archivo_1.js** es del cual quiero importar las funciones para utilizarlas

El **archivo_2.js** es el cual quiero exportar su contenido

**Contenido de Archivo_1.js**

```
import * as util from "archivo_2.js";
let util =require("./archivo2.js")

console.log(util)
```

**Contenido de Archivo_2,js**

```
export const funcion1 = () => {
    return "funcion1" };

export const funcion2 = () => {
    return "funcion2" }

export {
    funcion1,
    funcion2 }
```

Entonces me gustaría saber en que estoy fallando.
Mi idea no es crear un no se, index.html que tenga un tag script

```
<script type="module" src="archivo_1.js"></script>
```

solo Quiero trabajar libre con mi archivo_1.js y ejecutarlo con node archivo_1.js

Estoy confundiendo terminos?
Tiene que ser de esta forma?
Muchas gracias y espero que se entienda todo, sino con gusto trato de explicarme más.
Saludos!

---

***Actualizacion:***
Gracias por sus respuestas
Finalmente investigando me di cuenta de ciertas cosas y puede que a algunos les sirva.

Recorda quejavascript funciona de parte del Cliente y nodejs de parte del servidor.
Entonces, javascript vanilla usa import.
Nodejs utiliza require.

Cuando usamos import en js vanilla esta tiene que estar enlazado a un archivo index.html donde el script debe ser tipo module y montado en un liverServer o te tirará distintos tipos de errores entre los cuales destaca CORS.

La duda que sigue molestandome es que como podría hacer uso del require o import en el caso de que quiero tener un archivo suelto que requiera este import
Es decir no se, abrir mi vscode, crear un archivox.js y un archivo libs.js donde interactuen entre si para después ejecutar el archivox.js con "node archivox.js" sin problemas

Comment: segun tengo entendido ```require()``` buscara primero en la carpeta ```node_modules``` y ```import``` no (ES6), por lo que veo ambos hacen lo mismo.

Comment: @christian ambos hacen lo mismo, pero resumidamente, `require` solo se usa con `NodeJS` mientras que `import` se usa en `JS`, sin embargo creo que en las versiones mas recientes de `NodeJS` la sentencia `import` ya existe pero debe ser usada de manera especial.